# In relation with the set of Fredholm perturbation elements

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two unital Banach algebras and $T\colon A\to B$ an homomorphism  of Banach algebras. Let denote the set of  Fredholm perturbation elements in $A$, i.e.

$\operatorname{Ft}:=\{r\in A:T(a+r)\mbox{ is invertible in }B \mbox{ iff }T(a) \mbox{ is invertible in }B\}$.

I NEED a clear answer for this questions :

Why $\operatorname{Ft}$ is closed?

Please help me.

Comment: Is the $a$ in $Ft$ the same $a$ as in $polyFt$, in which case this is ill stated? Or should we read for all $a\in A$ in the definition of $Ft$?

Comment: for all a verifying T(a) invertible in A